# how to know the timezone name from utc time offset in javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone

How to know the timezone name from UTC offset in Javascript.

I have UTC offset, say

```
UTC+5:30,
```

I need to know where this timezone location is, like I want to get 
`'Asia/Calcutta'.`

If I give 
'`UTC+9`'
, then I need to get 
`Asia/Tokyo`

How to do this in Javascript?

Comment: There may be more than one timezone with a given offset at any one time. At best you can get a *list* of timezones which have that particular offset.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get that using `Intl` API. You can find the demo at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions

Comment: Can you explain how to give 'UTC+9' to this api and get 'Asia/Tokyo'. I am not getting it from the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You can try that:

```
console.log(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```